# не работает алгоритм

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

```
let arr = [];   
a = prompt();
for(let i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Number(a[i]);
}
arr = arr.reverse();

let check123 = true;

for(let i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == 1 || arr[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            alert("no");
            check123 = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
while(check123) {
let plus = 0;
let check = true;
let result = 0;
let potenz = 1;
for(let cycle = 0; cycle<arr.length; cycle++) {
if(arr[cycle] == 0) {
    potenz++;
    } else if(check && arr[0] == 1) {
        plus = 1;
        potenz++;
    } else {
        arr[cycle] = arr[cycle] * 2;
        arr[cycle] = arr[cycle] ** potenz;
        result += arr[cycle];
        potenz++;
}
    check = false;
}
check123 = false;
alert(result+plus);
}
```

при вводе 111000 он должен выводить 56, т.е. должен переводить двоичный код в десятичный, но выводит 112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function fromBinaryArray(arr) {
  return parseInt(arr.join(''), 2);
}

console.log(fromBinaryArray([1,1,1,0,0,0]));
```

```js
function fromBinaryArray(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc * 2 + el, 0);
}

console.log(fromBinaryArray([1,1,1,0,0,0]));
```

Comment: нет, что вы, я тренируюсь писать свои алгоритмы. Как еще мне учится программировать, кроме как набивать руку?

Comment: @Степан Хорошо, тогда второй вариант.

Answer (score 1):

нет, все исправил когда изменил `potenz = 1` на `potenz = 0`.